# 2GP push to default scratch org

Tags: managed-package, 2gp, push

I am in a managed package , the language of my dev hub is french and I think that create me some error when I tried to push on a SO (french or english) I receive the following error :

```
/Users/Name/Desktop/SF/Powerbi/PowerBi-original/force-app/main/default/objects/PowerBIDashboard__c/fields/Number__c.field-meta.xml        Cannot modify managed object: entity=CustomFieldDefinition, component=00N1x00000V66Nq, state=MANAGED_RELEASED, Field: Datatype Previous Value: Numéro New Value: Number (168:13)                      

/Users/Name/Desktop/SF/Powerbi/PowerBi-original/force-app/main/default/objects/PowerBIDashboard__c/fields/URLDashboard__c.field-meta.xml  Cannot modify managed object: entity=CustomFieldDefinition, component=00N1x00000V66Nr, state=MANAGED_RELEASED, Field: Datatype Previous Value: Zone de texte longue New Value: Long Text Area (180:13)

/Users/Name/Desktop/SF/Powerbi/PowerBi-original/force-app/main/default/objects/PowerBIDashboard__c/fields/Number__c.field-meta.xml        Cannot modify managed object: entity=CustomFieldDefinition, component=00N1x00000V66Nq, state=MANAGED_RELEASED, Field: Datatype Previous Value: Numéro New Value: Number (168:13)
```

this error was fixed but seem to come back
https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p4V000001U7sTQAS
anyone have an idea ?

Comment: did you solve the problem?
I am having the same problem

Comment: no sorry, I call SF they solve it